# "different but same"

Tags: single-word-requests, idiom-requests, phrase-requests

I would like to know if there are any words that express the idea of something being *"different, but the same"*. I'm open to interpretations, such as negative/duplicitous (wolf in sheep's clothing) but I'm really wondering if there's a specific term for this idea that something appears to be new and alien, but is actually familiar.

I realize there's an asian phrase "same-same but different", and that seems to be the reverse of what I'm looking for, as it promises something you know but is quite disparate in the end.

Comment: Adapting the construction you mentioned, *different-different but same*? :P

Comment: Consider *equivalent*, *similar*, or your own term, *familiar*. For an idiom, *there's nothing new under the sun*. Which term is most appropriate depends on how you intend to use it. Please [edit] your question to [provide some context](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info) for the word/idiom/expression you're asking for.

Comment: **Old wine in a new bottle** will look like *'different-different but same'*!

Comment: There is such a term but few of us see as applying outside biology or natural history.

*Variety* prolly isn't defined that way in any dictionary, but isn't it precisely the relationship of a *variety* to its *species*?

(I love mahmud's wine reference… )

Answer (score 1):

There is the idiom ***the more things change, the more they stay the same***.

> Many things remain consistent even as changes happen. The phrase is often said in a resigned or sarcastic tone.
>    *We move into a fancy new office, and still, the server crashes all the time. The more things change, the more they stay the same.*
>   <sub>[The Free Dictonary by FARLEX](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/the+more+things+change%2C+the+more+they+stay+the+same)</sub>

There are similar expressions such as ***different name, same game***, or ***same crap, different day***.

Answer (score 0):

> > "It's just last year's model with a **new coat of paint**."
> >
> > "It's just last year's model with a **facelift**."